# Why does okhttp3 connection pool use Int.MAX_VALUE as maximumPoolSize?

Tags: java, threadpool, okhttp

When a large number of requests are executed, a large number of threads are created to maintain idle connections, and these threads are in the TIMED_WAITING state for five minutes.

The following source code exists in the latest version:

```java
class RealBackend(threadFactory: ThreadFactory) : Backend {
  private val executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(
      0, // corePoolSize.
      Int.MAX_VALUE, // maximumPoolSize.
      60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, // keepAliveTime.
      SynchronousQueue(),
      threadFactory
  )
}
```

From [okhttp/TaskRunner.kt at master · square/okhttp · GitHub](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/concurrent/TaskRunner.kt#L271)

Connection pool source code: [okhttp/ConnectionPool.kt at master · square/okhttp · GitHub](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okhttp3/ConnectionPool.kt#L47)

Similar feedback in the GitHub repository issue:

- [About the "okhttp3" thread pool issue · Issue #5607 · square/okhttp · GitHub](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5607)
- [ConnectionPool ThreadPool why use Integer.MAX_VALUE maximumPoolSize param ? · Issue #5963 · square/okhttp · GitHub](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5963)

Why not use a lower value to limit the peak number of threads? Too high thread count may cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OkHttp limits its own resource usage limits, but not here. Instead, `Dispatcher` limits how many calls are in flight concurrently, and `ConnectionPool` limits how many connections are alive.

Comment: The current implementation is almost equivalent to `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`. Are you considering lowering the maximumPoolSize and matching an unbounded queue to avoid excessively high thread count? Because after sending a large number of requests, our monitoring system has detected a large number of connection pool threads.

Comment: Does your system [share its OkHttpClient](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/#okhttpclients-should-be-shared)? What version of OkHttp? It’s likely a configuration problem if you have more than 1 connection pool thread.

Comment: After I checked the code of our project, I found that the singleton OkHttpClient was indeed not used. This generated a large number of threads named OkHttp ConnectionPool. I read the `RealConnectionPool` source code of version 3.14.2. The `cleanupRunning` variable ensures that there will be at most a cleanup thread per connection pool. Thank you for your patience to answer, it is our problem.